# How can i prevent that the ItemAdd Event firing again after item.save

Tags: vba, outlook

How can i prevent that the ItemAdd Event firing again after item.save
At the moment i get an endless loop

```
Private Sub yFld_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    If Left(item.Subject, 16) Like "Visit from Mail:" And IsNumeric(Mid(item.Subject, 17)) Then
    x = newVisit(CLng(Mid(item.Subject, 17)))
    item.Subject = "checked: " & item.Subject & " " & x
    item.Save
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flag to deside to save item or not:

```
Dim ItemChecked as Boolean

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
   ...
   ItemChecked = False
End Sub

Private Sub yFld_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

   If Not ItemChecked Then
   ...
      mail.Save()                     
      ItemChecked = True       
   Else
      ItemChecked = False
   End If
End Sub
```

It works in my case.

Comment: This will only work if there is and always will be only one item in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

ItemAdd will not fire. ItemChange will.

Comment: sorry, but it does in my case

Comment: Do you see that behavior in OutlookSpy? Go to the folder in question, click the Folder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the Items property, click Browse, go to the Events tab. Do you see the event firing twice in the log at the bottom of the tab?